# Is it a good practice to Create Interface for Views in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, user-controls

In MVVM pattern generally we have the interface defined for `ViewModel` and not the `View` and use it for unit testing.

I created an `UserControl` which is consumed by many Super `UserControls`, for simplicity I have a factory which creates the `View Object` of the Inner `UserControl`.

When I want to test the Super `UserControl`, I need to mock the factory created  Inner `UserControl`.
Should I create a dummy interface which has properties defined like `ItemSource` or `DataContext` and mock it for testing? or is there any better approach?

These properties `ItemSource` or `DataContext` will be implemented by its base class of the User Control I am deriving from and not by my inner `UserControl`.

Comment: I believe if you want to test the View which is the actual UI for your application you should be doing this with an automated test suite - you shouldn't be trying to write unit tests in code for this.

Comment: If your UserControl has some application logic inside the implementation (class) then this is wrong, the application logic should be in a ViewModel and accessed via XAML bindings & commands.

Comment: I am testing the view model of the super user control. I am injecting the context menu into the super user control using a factory. Hope it makes sense.